# laravel date format full month, example : "7 January 2015"

Tags: php, date, laravel

i'm new on laravel & php... how to get date with format like bellow :
day-full month-full year

```
7-January-2015
```

how to do that?

Comment: `date("j F Y", strtotime("7 January 2015")`

Comment: Hi! Please visit the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section to see what is expected from questioners when/before asking. SO is not a code writing service!

Comment: `$start_day = date("d-M-Y");`

`echo $start_day;`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Carbon`:

```
$date = Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('j-f-Y');
```

More about `Carbon` here: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: `j-f-Y` should be `j-F-Y` to get the proper full month name